# What is "about://(null) It's working!!!" on my iPad?

Tags: ipad

Screenshot today. It popped up about six times in a row. [image]

Comment: What apps were running at the time?

Comment: I was on imgur. Sometimes a screen pops up saying "adtracking" and takes me to the app store. Just happened again, but now says about://(null) payload tested

Comment: The wifi signal bar is not there, but I'm connected.

Comment: did you use the candy cane game ?